# Making a discord bot that takes a screenshot every 5 minutes and posts it to a specific channel. I'm newer and not really sure what to do next

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that would take a screenshot of my screen, then post it to discord, and repeat this task every 5 minutes. It seems pretty simple, but I'm pretty new, and have been doing research and not really sure at this point what I've done wrong.

```
import discord
import pyautogui
import time
import datetime

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
        
    if datetime.datetime.now().minute % 5 == 0: 
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\discord-screenshot-bot-master\screenshot1.png')
channel = client.get_channel(779889991723122708)
channel.send(file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\discord-screenshot-bot-master\screenshot1.png'))
time.sleep(60)


client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

Comment: Did it generate an error? If so, what?

Comment: It did, I ended up figuring it out, It was due to indentation. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Please don't use time.sleep, use asyncio.sleep