# Discord.py Python Bot the bot goes offline in discord after approximately 5 minutes. but continues to do its job

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

Below is my code, I made a bot using Discord.Py, Its basis is to take a screenshot, then post the screenshot to discord, it is supposed to repeat this process every 5 minutes continuously. this works within my script, however after a bit the bot then goes offline in discord, and is no longer under its role, or under online members, and is shown offline. Is their a way to force the bot to stay online?

```
import pyautogui
import pyscreeze
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

class MyClient(discord.Client) :
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('online')
        game = discord.Game("Watching Logs")
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)
        while True:
            time.sleep(300 - time.time() % 300) 
            im1 = pyscreeze.screenshot()
            im2 = pyscreeze.screenshot(r'C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\discord-screenshot-bot-master\371logs.png')
            print('Screenshot Taken')
            time.sleep(5)
            channel = client.get_channel(780053606753239050)
            await channel.send('371 Logs')
            await channel.send(file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\discord-screenshot-bot-master\371logs.png'))
            print('Screenshot Posted to Discord')
client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the bot on a computer you own, or is it being hosted? Some hosts might consider a sleeping Python program to be "inactive". Also, can you see the stdout it is printing? It might be crashing you not know it. Also, you might want to check out the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module. If you want it, here is a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).

(This looks pretty similar to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950684/making-a-discord-bot-that-takes-a-screenshot-every-5-minutes-and-posts-it-to-a-s)...)

EDIT:

Discord's python module has some pretty weird error catching, as it is intended for use with `logging`.

Here is a snippet of code from my own Discord bot:

```
import logging
import discord

logger = logging.getLogger("discord")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # Do not allow DEBUG messages through
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="bot.log", encoding="utf-8", mode="w")
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("{asctime}: {levelname}: {name}: {message}", style="{"))
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

If you want more messsages (for example, when debugging, as you are now), comment out `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # Do not allow DEBUG messages through`.

Comment: To your "This looks pretty similar to this page" that was a previous question i asked. It wasn't working, ended up fixing it was just due to indentation which i had no idea because i'm new to python.... Also I'm running it off my computer. What do you mean by the stdout?

Comment: Stdout is the "file" Python defaults to printing to. If you look at the print function documentation, you see the file defaults to ```sys.stdout```. (sys is a module you can import.)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print